# How to make user click numbers in divs in ascending order?

Tags: javascript

I need to create a game with pure JS. I generate 16 numbers in 16 divs in an random order and the user is supposed to click those numbers in 10 seconds in ascending order if the user fails the game ends.

How to make sure that the next div user clicks contains number 2?

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");

function generisi() {
  let niz = new Set()
  var i = 0;

  while (niz.size < 16) {
    niz.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * 16) + 1);
    console.log(niz);
  }

  niz = Array.from(niz);

  for (var j = 0; j < divs.length; j++) {
    divs[j].innerHTML = '<p class="broj">' + parseInt(niz[j]) + '</p>';
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
  divs[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (var j = 0; j < divs.length; j++) {
      if (divs[j].getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerText == 1) {
        divs[j].getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerText = ""
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Please revise the snippet I created to add some HTML and fix the missing characters at the end.

Comment: @James The OP is using a `Set`, so it won't be all 8s, and they're looping based on the `size` of the `Set`, so eventually it will contain all of the numbers. It would be faster to simply create an ordered array, then shuffle it, but, whatever.

Comment: I would just remember what the last number clicked was, defaulting to 0, and if the next number clicked is not that number + 1, the user fails.

Comment: @HereticMonkey would that work tho? If i go through a loop of divs and if it checks for 1 and 1+1 and the user clicks on one of those both of those numbers will go away

Comment: Is there by any chance a function/command in JS that lets you get innerHTML of that clicked Div?

Comment: Add the event argument to the event handler (e.g., `addEventListener("click", function(e) {` ), then use `e.target.innerText` (to get the text without any HTML tags). You don't need the inner loop at all; just `var thisClick = parseInt(e.target.innerText); if (thisClick !== lastClick + 1) { /* fail */ } else { e.target.innerText = ''; }` You might need to adjust the `else` block to match your HTML structure (since you haven't told us what that is, I can't give a good answer).

Comment: @HereticMonkey on the first number it works but on the next one it wont work                    if(divs.target.innerText == 1){
            firstClick=parseInt(divs.target.innerText);
            divs.target.innerText=" ";
            
       }
       var nextClick= parseInt(divs.target.innerText);
       if(nextClick == (firstClick+1)){
            divs.target.innerText=" ";
        }

Comment: remove `if(divs.target.innerText == 1){ firstClick=parseInt(divs.target.innerText); divs.target.innerText=" "; }` and add `var firstClick = 0;` outside of the event handler. Add `firstClick = nextClick;` inside the `if(nextClick == (firstClick+1)){` block. Also, make sure you're using the event argument passed to the event handler as mentioned in my previous comment. The fact that you are using a variable named `divs` is worrisome.

Comment: @HereticMonkey IT WORKS! Thank you so much! I changed the divs to e, thanks!!!